# android size of remote file in java

Tags: android, file, size

I guess this quesiton has been answered already, buy it doesn't seem to work, and it is very furstrating...
I am just trying to get the size of a remote file in Android.
So far, I have tried the following two approaches, without success:

1)

```
try
{
 file = new File("http://50.19.156.118/feed2/storage/download/a_17/Madagascar.3gp");
 a=(int) myFileBeingUploaded.length();
}
catch (Exception j)
{
}
```

2)

```
try
{
 url = new URL("http://50.19.156.118/feed2/storage/download/a_17/Madagascar.3gp);
 urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 a=urlConnection.getContentLength();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
}
```

getContentLength() returns always 77 !!, while File.length() returns 0

Any ideas?
Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

HTTP is not a filesystem -- it is a protocol for communicating hyperlinked resources. With standard HTTP, the only way to determine the size of a resource is to download that resource. The way to solve your problem, assuming that you want the size *before* you want the resource, is to implement another resource which tells you the size. True, the Content-Size field of a response tells you the size of the data contained in the response, but only after you request the resource.

e.g. given your web server with image portrait.jpg, you could set up a php script meta.php to which you pass the name of the resource of interest... `meta.php?f=portrait.jpg`. Then meta.php would ask its filesystem for the size of `f` and return that number via HTTP.